# The best way to delete items in hierarchy way from a DB table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table of categories. Two of its columns are 'category_id' and 'parent_category' which i am using for deletion .
The values of these columns are aligned as :

[image]

e.g. if i am deleting 'category_id' 10 then all its children(to any depth) 11,12,13 should also be deleted. please suggest me the best mysql query.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way seems to be this:

1. Create a foreign key constraint between the `parent_category` and `category_id` column;
2. Set cascade delete on.

   ```
   create table yourTable
   ( ...
     add constraint
     foreign key (parent_category)
     references yourTable(category_id)
     on delete cascade
   )
   ```

This will solve your problem totally without effort.

Comment: thnx it is working but i had to add a row with category_id=0 .

Comment: Okay. I don't think it is really necessary, but I don't know the specific situation. Does it bother you? Try making the parent_category nullable. That should work.

Comment: Because categories with 0 parent_ids have been parents here.

Comment: That seems reasonable. You can also set them to null too if you want to.

Comment: Now its perfect :-) . it was that NULL ,i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use foreign keys, so you can add a column `parent_path`

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD `parent_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
AFTER `parent_category`, COMMENT='';
```

Now create a procedure that creates the `parent_path`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateParentPath$$

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateParentPath()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE count INT;
        SET count = 1;

        WHILE count > 0 DO
            UPDATE `table` as `t`
                LEFT JOIN `table` as `p` ON `t`.`parent_category` = `p`.`category_id`
            SET `t`.`parent_path` = CONCAT(`p`.`parent_path`, IF(`p`.`parent_path` = '', '', ','), `p`.`category_id`);

            SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO count;
        END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call this procedure

```
CALL UpdateParentPath();
```

And now ... finally ... you start deleting

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `parent_category` = '9' OR `parent_path` LIKE '%,9,%'
```

Before every deleting or after insert/update is necessary call `UpdateParentPath` procedure.